# How to pass a variable to predicate expression?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I'm creating `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` expression tree dynamically:

```cs
int id = ...;
Expression<Func<Entity, int>> keySelector = e => e.Id;
BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(
   keySelector.Body, 
   Expression.Constant(id, keySelector.Body.Type)); //replace this with a variable

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(equals, keySelector.Parameters[0]);
```

which produces equivalent of `e => e.Id == 1`.

How do I pass a variable instead of a constant: `e => e.Id == id`

Comment: The same way the C# compiler does it: create a closure class that holds `id` as a property (or field), make the expression a method of that class so it can reference that, and wire it up. The code for this is not trivial; if you have a true need for dynamic LINQ there are libraries that take care of this (like the unimaginatively but aptly named DynamicLinq).

Comment: Warp your expression in a Func like so: Func<int, Expression<Func<Entity, int>>>, the int of your first Func is your id

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I hoped there will be a sample for it. I'm not sure I really need a closure class, because I only need it for EF core so that it genereates SQL Parameter, e.g.: `WHERE ID=@id` instead of constant: `WHERE ID=1`.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen: I need to pass it to EF Core, so I cannot change the signature.

Comment: @liero, yes but its a func so you call the func before passing it to EF and the return value is Expression<Func<Entity, int>>>

Comment: @JochemVanHespen: I'm not sure it works this way. Could you demonstrate it here, please: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fJ0oMM?

Comment: @Liero you are right I miss understand your question, the equals comes from binary expression. But here [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/evuJZJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the const to something that you can change a property of:

```
class IDHolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

now you bind your expression to instance of IDHolder like so:

```
var idHolder = new IDHolder { Id = 0 };
Expression<Func<Entity, int>> keySelector = e => e.Id;

BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(
    keySelector.Body,
           
    Expression.Property(
        Expression.Constant(idHolder, typeof(IDHolder)),
    nameof(IDHolder.Id))
           
    );

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(equals, keySelector.Parameters[0]);
```

the predicate becomes slightly more complicated yet nothing that would make EF break:

```
x => x.Id == idHandler.Id
```

you can test this by compiling the predicate and running simple tests changing Id and the entity:

```
var func = predicate.Compile();

idHolder.Id = 5;

Console.WriteLine(func(new Entity { Id = 0 }).ToString());  // false
Console.WriteLine(func(new Entity { Id = 5 }).ToString());  // true

idHolder.Id = 6;

Console.WriteLine(func(new Entity { Id = 6 }).ToString());   // true
```

note that this approach is not thread safe and will result in strange behavior if you cache predicate and idHolder and use that in web api project or anything potentially using this predicate concurrently.  To just auto translate some conditions from requests it would be better to just create the expression each time you need to use it in EF. There is no significant performance hit while creating expressions; the costly operation is the compilation and that is never done by EF.

---

Or maybe I misunderstood your question and you simply need a way to change the value of id, and as suggested by @Jochem Van Hespen you need a function:

```
public Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> GetPredicate(int id){

    Expression<Func<Entity, int>> keySelector = e => e.Id;
    BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(
       keySelector.Body, 
       Expression.Constant(id, keySelector.Body.Type)); 

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(equals, keySelector.Parameters[0]);
    return predicate;
    }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
 _dbContext.Set<Entity>().Where(GetPredicate(4))
```

Comment: You understood correctly. You can remove the part below the horizontal line